# Thank helpful people

Tags: discussion

What's a good way to thank a person who gave you an answer or comment? I know that extraneous conversation is discouraged in answers and comments.

If there's not a mechanism, I'd like to request one. There are kind and knowledgeable people who made and effort to help me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "Stackexchange Way" to say thank you is to give reputation points by "upvoting" a post you found helpful, and by "accepting" the most helpful answer to your question.

These basics are nicely explained in our [tour](https://german.stackexchange.com/tour) and the [help section](https://german.stackexchange.com/help). Both are accessible from the top bar question mark.

Indeed comments or extra lines in posts to say thank you are discouraged as they lead to a lot of clutter which will not be of much value over time. Think of Stack Exchange as a huge database of knowledge made for future visitors.

Also please do not serial upvote a user just for saying thank you. The system will detect this and will revert all those votes after a while. Always vote on a single post's content rather than on the user who wrote it. It again is the long-term usability we have in mind.

If it was a **really, really** helpful post you can also give away a [bounty](https://german.stackexchange.com/help/bounty) to a fellow user. This will deduct some of your reputation (starting from 50) and you can give it to that user the day after you had started it. Sometimes you may get an even better answer by doing so.

Sadly our [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/499/deutschsprachiger-raum) is not so frequented as we would like it to be. You probably will not meet a certain user there. But it would be a good place for all kind of chatter including gratefulness. It is always worth a try.